# Bilinear form: find the maximal sub-space in which $q$ is not atrophied

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, trace, bilinear-form

Let $V := M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and let function $f : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f \left( A, B \right) = 2 \mbox{tr} \left( A B \right) -\mbox{tr} \left( A \right) \mbox{tr} \left( B \right)$$

I showed that it is a bilinear form on $V$ and I found that the rank of its quadratic form $q$ is $9$, and the sign is $(9,0)$.

The next exercise is to find a subspace of $V$ of maximal dimension that $q|_W$ is nondegenerate.

Comment: I think it means whoever wrote that made a bad typo. I have never seen the term “atrophied” for bilinear forms, or in math generally. Ask your instructor what it was supposed to be. Perhaps it should be anisotropic?

Comment: Is this question translated from some other language? What is a "withered/atrophied" quadratic form? Does it mean a degenerate quadratic form?